# php looping to add up a sum?

Tags: php

What do I use for a variable which will count the total amount?

For example

```
if ($featured == "1"){
    $cost = 100;
}else{
    $cost = 1000;
}
```

Basically each time that is looped, we display the `$cost` on page, but I also want to set aside a variable `$total` which adds up each `$cost` as the loop runs.

Comment: you shoudl work on you accept-rate (52% looks a bit low) - this will bring you more an (hopeful) better aswers. from the FAQ: When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (If you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but really?

```
$total = 0; // this somewhere before the loop

// start loop
if ($featured == "1") {
    $cost = 100;
} else {
    $cost = 1000;
}

$total += $cost;
// end loop
```